# VB - FileSystem.GetFileInfo taking too long

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows

I have an application that I run on a Virtual Machine (Windows 7, VS 2013, .NET 4.5.1) that runs perfectly fine, but when I try to run the same application on my local machine (Windows 10, VS 2015, .NET 4.6), it slows to a crawl.

I've narrowed the issue down to a FileSystem.GetFileInfo call on files on a remote shared drive, and while the VM has always been quicker on this, the amount of additional time it's taking doesn't seem to make sense.

```
Dim remoteFileInfo As FileInfo    
remoteFileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(RemotePath & filename)
```

I was recently upgraded to Win10/VS2015/NET 4.6 on my local machine, and when I ran this same program prior to the upgrade, there was a difference that was more in line with a ping timer built into the application.  The VM had a ping of basically 0, while the local machine had a ping of about 50ms.  After the upgrade, the ping timer on my local machine still shows about 50ms, but it's taking about 3s per cycle (for roughly 300 files, it adds up).

If I skip the process that includes this line everything else seems to run fine, but this application is designed to kick off other executables so it needs to make sure it has the latest version of those executables to run.

Are there any hidden tricks that I should watch out for with my new setup?

Comment: [FileSystem.GetFileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) does some checks that can result in an exception; however, most of those are eaten in a try-catch and your code will never see them.  The delay you are experiencing smells of a delay caused by exception handling.  Why not just instantiate `New System.IO.FileInfo(file path string)` directly and use its `Exists` property?

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: @TnTinMn: I've made the changes, but still seem to be getting the same results. If it helps at all, there's also a lag on remotefileinfo.LastWriteTime, though it tends to be shorter.